# What am I doing wrong that my loops are processing the entire directory listing instead of each individual file name?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, scripting, torrent

I have written a script that will take torrent files from Dropbox, add them to Transmission and move the torrent to another location. The script is working for me, as long as I only put one file within a folder at a time. If I have multiple files in the folder, it will give me an error about file path being too long. Can anyone tell from my script below what I am doing wrong and how I can change it so that it can properly process multiple files? This is a bash script on a Mac that get executed every 60 seconds via launchd.

Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash
# Log to debug file
set –xv; exec 1>>/Users/admin/TorrentMoverLog.txt 2>&1
date
###################################################
###                                             ###
###             Torrent Mover  v.0.1            ###
###                                             ###
###################################################

#################  Variables  #####################
###################################################
######## Watch Folders                           ##
##                                               ##
WATCH_PATH=/Users/admin/Dropbox/Torrent-Drop/
WATCH_FOLDERS=( Movies/ TV/ Music/ FLAC/ Software/ Other/ )
##                                               ## 
######## DL Folders                              ##
##                                               ##
DL_PATH=/Volumes/Media/
##                                               ##
###################################################


################  Functions  ######################
###################################################
##                                               ##
function add_torrent {
    /usr/local/bin/transmission-remote -a "$1" -w "$2""$3"
}
##                                               ##
###################################################

###################  Script  ######################
##                                               ##
## Rename files with spaces
echo "Renaming files with spaces"
find "$WATCH_PATH" -depth -name "* *" -execdir rename 's/ /_/g' "{}" \;

## Start Outer Loop
## Process Watch Folders
for wf in "${WATCH_FOLDERS[@]}"
do
    WF_LIST=`ls $WATCH_PATH${wf} | grep torrent`
    ## Check for torrent files first, skip if none found
    if [ "$WF_LIST" != "" ]; then
        echo "Processing ${wf} folder..."
        ## Start Inner Loop
        ## Process Files within watch folders
        ## Set download folder
            for torrent in "$WF_LIST";
            do
                case "${wf}" in

                Movies/ ) echo "Movies variable set"
                    DL_FOLDER=Movies/ ;;

                TV/ ) echo "TV variable set"
                    DL_FOLDER=TV_Shows/ ;;

                Music/ ) echo "Music variable set"
                    DL_FOLDER=Music/ ;;

                FLAC/ ) echo "FLAC variable set"
                    DL_FOLDER=PlexMusic/ ;;

                Software/ ) echo "Software variable set"
                    DL_FOLDER=Software/ ;;

                Other/ ) echo "Other variable set"
                    DL_FOLDER=Other/ ;;

                esac
                ## Add torrent to transmission
                echo "Running command, add_torrent $WATCH_PATH${wf}$torrent $DL_PATH $DL_FOLDER"
                add_torrent "$WATCH_PATH${wf}$torrent" "$DL_PATH" "$DL_FOLDER"
                ## Move torrent
                echo "Moving $WATCH_PATH${wf}$torrent to $DL_PATH""TorrentFiles/"
                mv "$WATCH_PATH${wf}$torrent" "$DL_PATH""TorrentFiles/"
            done
        ## End Inner Loop
        echo "Finished processing torrents in ${wf} folder."
    else
        echo "Skipping ${wf} directory, no torrents found."
    fi  
done
## End Outer Loop

exit 0
```

Comment: Using `ls` in a script **at all** is wrong. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: ...and btw, using the `function` keyword is bad form. `add_torrent() { ... }`, with no `function`, is the POSIX-compliant way to define a shell function.

Comment: You do take care to rename any files with spaces, but then you iterate over `"$WF_LIST"`, not `$WF_LIST`, so `torrent` only gets set to one value, the space-delimited list of all files, rather than each individual file one at a time. Note, though, that whitespace isn't the only reason to avoid parsing the output of `ls`.

Comment: ...also, all-caps variable names are bad form. See fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a namespace.

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/182408/how-to-automatically-launch-a-shell-script-when-content-of-a-given-directory-is for approaches to run your script only when the directory is changed, rather than needing to poll every minute.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their other input regarding functions, and variables. This is why this community is so great, ask one question, get many answers as well as other issues pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is [trying to parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) rather than using a glob expression.

```
shopt -s nullglob # make globs return empty set on failure to match
for torrent in "$WATCH_PATH/$wf"/*torrent*; do
  echo "Found $torrent"
done
```

---

...or, to store glob results in an array:

```
shopt -s nullglob # can just put this once at the top of your script
wf_list=( "$WATCH_PATH/$wf/"*torrent* )
echo "Found ${#wf_list[@]} torrents:"
for torrent in "${wf_list[@]}"; do
  printf '- %q\n' "$torrent"
done
```

---

If you took the quotes off -- `for torrent in $WF_LIST` -- that would enable string-splitting and glob expansion on the output of `ls`, but this itself is buggy (breaks filenames with spaces, breaks filenames which can be interpreted as glob expansions, etc). Don't do it.